# Angular 7 : close menu when click outside

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I would like to know whenever click is triggered inside parent div #menu, irrelavant of html tags exists inside it.

nativeElement.parent didn't worked for me.

HTML code:

```
<button #toggleButton (click)="toggleMenu()"> Toggle Menu</button>

 <div class="menu" *ngIf="isMenuOpen" #menu>
    <div>
      I'm the menu. Click outside to close me
    </div>
    </div>
```

Angular script:

```
this.renderer.listen('window', 'click',(e:Event)=>{

        if(e.target !== this.toggleButton.nativeElement && e.target!==this.menu.nativeElement){
            this.isMenuOpen=false;
        }
    });
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 14):

Add Host to component meta tag.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  host: {
    "(window:click)": "onClick()"
  }
})
```

**stopPropagation()**

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further
>   propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
toggleMenu($event) {    
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }

  onClick() {
    this.isMenuOpen = false;
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oenkbw

Comment: Didn't know about the host (window:click) listener , that's neat. Well done ;)

Comment: The menu closes if you click inside of it

Answer (score 2):

you can reset menus state by listen to document click event in that case any click event in the menus need to run event `stopPropagation`method to prevent document click method , finally any click in the body of menus component gone to handle by you 
and any click event outside menus component `resetToggle` will run.

> stopPropagation this prevent document click handler to run

```
  menuItemClickHandler(e , index ) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   // something magical  ‍♂️✨
    ...
  }

  @HostListener("document:click") resetToggle() {
    this.isMenuOpen=false;
  }
```

menus componenet

```
export class MenusComponent {

  menuslist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  @HostBinding('class.active') isMenuOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  menuItemClickHandler(e, index) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // something magical  ‍♂️✨
    console.log(index);
    this.toggle(e); // toggle menus after you click 
  }
  // component click
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) click(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

  }
  @HostListener("document:click") resetToggle() {
    this.isMenuOpen = false;
  }

  toggle(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('toggle')
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }

}
```

menus component template

```
<ul ngClass="{slide : isMenuOpen}">
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuslist;let index=index" (click)="menuItemClickHandler($event,index)">
    {{item}}
  </li>
  </ul>
```

menus style will toggle menus to slide on or off base on menus is open value

```
:host {
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: -300px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
:host.active{
  margin-left: 0
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-menus)

Comment: I tried to make the changes. But it's not working. Menu has to close only when i click outside of it.  Here is the reference link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyhny6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: just remove this line `this.toggle(e); // toggle menus after you click `

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-menus-j8s1eh @Lavanya

Comment: When i add event.stopPropogation() method for menu, it's working as expected. HTML : <button #toggleButton (click)="toggleMenu()"> Toggle Menu</button>

<div class="menu" *ngIf="isMenuOpen" #menu>
  <div id="test" click-stop-propagation>
    <div>
I'm the menu. Click outside to close me
    </div>
</div>
</div>                                                                        
Angular :  @Directive({ selector: "[click-stop-stopPropagation]"
}) @HostListener("click",["$event"])
public onClick(event:any) :void {
event.stopPropagation();
}

Comment: @Lavanya toggle already clall `e.stopPropagation();`  ‍♂️ `<button (click)="m.toggle($event)">|||</button>`  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-menus-j8s1eh